# API for writing in textarea with HTML code

Tags: php

I want users to write HTML code, so they could format text and I could put that into database. I want users to be able to make lists, bold text, italic and I guess that's it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [ckeditor](http://www.ckeditor.com/).

CKEditor is a text editor to be used inside web pages. It's a WYSIWYG editor, which means that the text being edited on it looks as similar as possible to the results users have when publishing it. It brings to the web common editing features found on desktop editing applications like Microsoft Word and OpenOffice.

for replacing all text area with html editor refer below link.

http://svn.ckeditor.com/CKEditor/trunk/_samples/php/replaceall.php

Answer (score 0):

I just recently implemented Chipersoft's version of WYSIWYG Markdown Editor, works much like Stackoverflow's markdown editor.

You can save the markdown version in your database, then when you want to render it, you can use PHP Markdown to convert it from marked down to actual HTML tags.

These two apps work great together, and means less of a footprint in your database (and on filesystem), because you are not having to store the full blown html tags.

Markdown Editor: https://github.com/ChiperSoft/wmd

Markdown to HTML Converter: http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/